# Get multiple values from child from Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get multiple child values with one Firebase Listener?
For example I want to get the username and full name and save each of them in a string, how would I go about doing this. I'm guessing with a child event listener?
[image: Structure]

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

reference.child(user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      String name = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
      String fullName = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue(String.class);

  }
 @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      throw databaseError.toException();
     }
});
```

First get the current user, then reference the uid of the user, attach a listener and you can retrieve the values.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
for (DataSnapshot ALL_USERS: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
   String all_users=(ALL_USERS.getValue().toString());
   String name = all_users.child("username").getValue(String.class);
   String fullName = all_users.child("fullname").getValue(String.class);
}
```